# Having trouble getting a complete dataset from a mids object using MICE in R

Tags: r, r-mice

I simulated a dataset with missing not at random. And then I used mice()to impute it, but R does not return a complete dataset for me.

My code looks like:

```
tempData <- mice(data1)
completedData <- complete(tempData)
```

data1 is the dataset with missing. tempData is the mids object (this step is successful). But when I use complete(), R returns an error message:

> "Error in if (length(unique(colnames(data))) != ncol(data))
>   stop("items must have unique names in data input",  : argument is of
>   length zero"

Why this happens?

I have attached the dataset to replicate the error and provide the code to do this below:

```
data1<-read.delim("path where the file is stored",sep="\t")
tempData <- mice(data1)
completedData <- complete(tempData)
```

dataset:

```
"V1"    "V2"    "V3"    "V4"    "V5"    "V6"    "V7"    "V8"    "V9"    "V10"
"1" 1   NA  0   0   0   1   NA  0   NA  NA
"2" 0   0   NA  0   0   1   0   0   0   NA
"3" 0   1   NA  NA  NA  NA  1   1   NA  1
"4" 0   1   0   1   NA  1   NA  1   0   NA
"5" NA  NA  0   1   1   NA  0   0   0   NA
"6" NA  NA  1   0   NA  1   0   1   1   NA
"7" 0   1   NA  NA  NA  1   NA  0   0   NA
"8" 0   1   NA  0   0   NA  1   NA  0   1
"9" 0   1   0   0   0   NA  0   NA  0   1
"10"    NA  NA  NA  0   NA  1   0   NA  0   0
"11"    0   1   NA  0   0   NA  NA  NA  1   0
"12"    0   0   NA  0   NA  NA  0   1   NA  1
"13"    0   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0   1   0   NA
"14"    0   1   0   NA  NA  0   NA  NA  0   0
"15"    1   1   NA  NA  0   0   0   1   0   0
"16"    1   1   NA  0   NA  0   NA  0   NA  NA
"17"    NA  0   NA  NA  NA  0   NA  NA  NA  NA
"18"    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   0   0   1
"19"    NA  0   NA  0   NA  1   NA  NA  NA  0
"20"    0   NA  NA  NA  NA  0   NA  NA  1   NA
"21"    0   NA  0   0   NA  NA  NA  0   0   NA
"22"    0   1   0   0   0   NA  NA  0   NA  0
"23"    1   1   NA  0   NA  0   1   1   0   1
"24"    NA  NA  1   NA  0   NA  NA  1   0   1
"25"    0   0   0   NA  NA  NA  0   NA  NA  NA
"26"    0   1   NA  NA  0   NA  NA  NA  0   1
"27"    0   NA  NA  NA  0   0   1   0   0   0
"28"    NA  NA  NA  NA  0   0   NA  NA  1   1
"29"    NA  0   0   NA  1   0   0   NA  NA  0
"30"    NA  0   0   NA  0   0   NA  NA  NA  1
"31"    NA  1   0   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0   0
"32"    0   0   NA  0   0   0   NA  1   NA  NA
"33"    NA  1   1   0   0   0   0   NA  0   NA
"34"    NA  1   0   0   NA  0   0   NA  1   0
"35"    NA  1   0   0   NA  0   0   1   0   NA
"36"    NA  1   1   NA  0   0   1   0   0   NA
"37"    NA  NA  1   NA  NA  0   NA  NA  NA  0
"38"    NA  1   0   NA  NA  0   NA  NA  0   1
"39"    0   1   NA  0   NA  NA  1   1   0   NA
"40"    0   NA  NA  0   0   NA  NA  0   0   0
"41"    0   1   NA  0   0   NA  0   NA  NA  0
"42"    NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   0   0
"43"    NA  1   1   0   0   NA  0   1   NA  0
"44"    NA  0   NA  0   NA  0   NA  1   NA  NA
"45"    0   0   0   NA  0   NA  0   NA  0   NA
"46"    NA  1   0   0   NA  NA  0   1   NA  0
"47"    0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
"48"    1   1   NA  1   0   1   NA  0   NA  0
"49"    NA  NA  NA  0   0   NA  0   NA  NA  NA
"50"    1   1   1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  0   NA
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, without a [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example, we cannot offer concrete suggestions. Please update your post with a small dataset that replicates the error.

Comment: Can't reproduce this error. Does the error persist with a fresh R session (i.e. with only `mice` loaded)?